Determine if a firewall rule with a certain name exists
Simple question, how to compose an if else expression if a firewall rule named "rule X" exists? I found a dozen different examples, but they were either not working or too abstruse.
$r = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'Docker Cluster Management Communications' 2> $null; 
if ($r) { 
    write-host "found it"; 
} 
else { 
    write-host "did not find it" 
}

if((netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="** TCP Port 1433") -Contains "No rules match the specified criteria.")

{
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="** TCP Port 1433" dir=in protocol=TCP localport=1433 action=allow
}

if (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'Rule X' ) {
write-host "Firewall rule for Rule X  already exists, not creating new rule"
}


I don't need additional checks, I need one single WORKING check. What I've shown you doesn't work.

I want to make a script switch that on startup will create a rule if it doesn't exist, or delete it if it does. One of the two. Do you know how to do it without IF ELSE?

I repeat, I need ONE SCRIPT that, when started, checks if a rule exists, if it does, deletes it, and immediately, if it does NOT exist, creates it. Do you understand? One script should be able to create and delete a rule depending on whether it exists or not. You are offering two options, and I need both!

Something like this
@echo off netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="@Rule X" >nul 2>&1 if %errorlevel% neq 0 ( chcp 65001 netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="@Rule X" description="Test" dir=in program="%SystemDrive%\Test\common\Test app\app.exe" protocol=udp localport=6672 action=allow ) else ( netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="@Rule X" new enable=no netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="@Rule X" )
Working only

I understand your doubt and confusion, sometimes it is necessary to simplify the code as much as possible.
I have found the way to do what you want in a way that in my opinion is very simple with the following code:
$RuleExists = Get-NetFirewallRule | Where-Object DisplayName -eq "Docker Desktop Backend"

if ($RuleExists) {
    Write-Host "Found it"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Did not find it"
}

This is just an example, in your case you will need to change the DisplayName you are checking.
Regards!

Like this?  Run as admin.
if (get-netfirewallrule -displayname foo -ea 0) { 'yes' } else { 'no' }

